# Can I double the circuit on the same PCBDoc using Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb, schematics, altium

Can I double the number of components for a PCB while having a single schematic in Altium Designer? I want to make a two same circuit on the same board.

Or should I recreate the same schematic to double the number of component for PCB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the "[embedded board array](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-embedded-board-array?version=21)" feature to put several copies of a design on a pcb.

This is useful for panelization. The copies will be exact copies, and if the original PCB is modified, the copies will inherit the modifications.

Answer (score 4):

As well as the accepted answer, you can copy/paste (and re-annotate) all the components, or you can use rooms and a hierarchical schematic to repeat a given sub-circuit multiple times. You can layout one room and then copy the layout to the second with a couple clicks, then arrange any interconnections that might be necessary and/or move the rooms around on the PCB.